How can i avoid smearing when moving my images in a Canvas
I'm using konvajs to create a canvas that allows users to upload images and move/resize them, they can also choose a font and add some text.
However when i try to move the images they smear and leave a "trace" behind them, like a high exposure photo. Strangely enough this happens only on Apple phones and not in the built in firefox  emulator on my mac.
I tried to change the css, remove cache and basically any solution found on google but nothing worked.

Posting this since i couldn't find anyone on the internet with the same problem, after some time i found that when loading the fonts it failed on one of them (it got a pdf instead of a font) and  since this wasn't used by default somehow it didn't affect any device except iphones.
After changing it everything worked correctly on all devices.
If anyone has an explanation on why it affected the canvas the way it did I'm really curious.

Thanks for taking the time to come back and self-answer. Not experienced the issue myself so good to know what to suspect.
